# How to parse the attached XML in Swift and get all the account information from it

Tags: swift, xml

I'm new to Swift and finding it difficult to parse the linked XML in Swift language. I've tried using SWXMLHash pod library, but it didn't help me. I want to extract the account node information from the XML and store it in a structure.

[image: XML]

Comment: @karel Thanks for your comment.  I have updated the permission for the link.  Now it can be accessed by anyone without sign-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't mind using a third party library, you can try [XMLMapper](https://github.com/gcharita/XMLMapper) (similar to [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) but for XML)

Use the following model classes:

```
class GNCv2: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var gncAccounts: [GNCAccount]?

    required init?(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        gncAccounts <- map["gnc:book.gnc:account"]
    }
}

class GNCAccount: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var name: String?
    var id: AccountID?
    var type: String?
    var commoditySpace: String?
    var commodityID: String?
    var commoditySCU: Int?
    var description: String?
    var slots: AccountSlot?
    var parent: AccountID?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        name <- map["act:name"]
        id <- map["act:id"]
        type <- map["act:type"]
        commoditySpace <- map["act:commodity.cmdty:space"]
        commodityID <- map["act:commodity.cmdty:id"]
        commoditySCU <- map["act:commodity-scu"]
        description <- map["act:description"]
        slots <- map["act:slots.slot"]
        parent <- map["act:parent"]
    }
}

class AccountID: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var type: String?
    var value: String?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        type <- map.attributes["type"]
        value <- map.innerText
    }
}

class AccountSlot: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var key: String?
    var value: AccountSlotValue?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        key <- map["slot:key"]
        value <- map["slot:value"]
    }
}

class AccountSlotValue: XMLMappable {
    var nodeName: String!

    var type: String?
    var value: Bool?

    required init(map: XMLMap) {}

    func mapping(map: XMLMap) {
        type <- map.attributes["type"]
        value <- map.innerText
    }
}
```

And map your XML using `init(XMLString:)` function of the root object class (in this case `GNCv2`) like:

```
let gncv2 = GNCv2(XMLString: xmlString)
```

You can achieve the exact same thing by using the `map(XMLString:)` function of the `XMLMapper` like:

```
let gncv2 = XMLMapper<GNCv2>().map(XMLString: xmlString)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @gcharita.